# $filter Azure Audit logs

Tags: azure, filter, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azureportal

I am using the following API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I want to filter resources for only UserManagement category but for some reason the API call I am making gives me error

This is the exact API call

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=category/any(s:s eq 'UserManagement')`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-10T06:27:37",
            "request-id": "cfd471b2-8b13-4a43-b3de-c6a963425f8c",
            "client-request-id": "cfd471b2-8b13-4a43-b3de-c6a963425f8c"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error you're getting.

Comment: As per documentation "category" field is not supported by $filter, closing the question

Comment: I was about to write that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#attributes-supported-by-filter-parameter :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the lambda operator doesn't work but I can still query like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=category eq 'UserManagement'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to filter data using `startsWith` instead of `ne`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=startsWith(userPrincipalName, 'user.com#EXT#@dm4.onmicrosoft.com')
```